# Do I have to disable interrupts while in one?

Tags: c, interrupt, pic, microchip

Do I have to disable high interrupts while inside one, if I am using multiple interrupts on the Microchip C18?

Consider the code below:

```
#ifndef OTHER_INTERRUPT_H
#pragma interrupt InterruptHook // interrupt fname
void InterruptHook(void)
{
    #ifdef STEPPER_H
        Stepper_Interrupt();
    #endif

    #ifdef FLOW_H
        Flow_Interrupt();
    #endif
}
#endif
```

Should I follow the same approach as in the code here below? (I would then put the disables in appropriate places within the functions.)

```
#ifndef OTHER_INTERRUPT_H
#pragma interrupt InterruptHook // interrupt fname
void InterruptHook(void)
{
    #ifdef STEPPER_H
        INTCONbits.GIEH = 0;
        Stepper_Interrupt();
        INTCONbits.GIEH = 1;
    #endif

    #ifdef FLOW_H
        INTCONbits.GIEH = 0;    
        Flow_Interrupt();
        INTCONbits.GIEH = 1;
    #endif
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the hardware. Some processors automatically disable interrupts while servicing one. Others prioritize their interrupts, so that a more high-priority interrupt can still occur while a lower is being serviced.

The [Microchip PIC18](http://www.microchip.com/en_US/family/8bit/architecture/pic18.html) series microcontrollers feature multiple levels of hardware interrupts, and they can be optionally prioritized too.

Comment: hm.... this is code within high interrupt, two functions equally prioritised. I have one more pragma -> #pragma lowinterrupt InterruptHandler........ or maby I got it wrong so flow and stepper have different priorities whithin.